# Angularjs with ASP.Net core design

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, rest, web-services, asp.net-core

I am a beginner in web development, I have asp.net core applications from which i want to consume their Rest APIs in Angularjs client side, basically just some applications which have a web interface, and i want to use their Rest APIs from my UI in "Angularjs" :

I am thinking of design, is it enough to have Angularjs beside html css , and this will just consume my Rest APIs urls "already I have " , or i need to do interface between the Rest APIs and Angularjs part ? , propably node.js or even python , I am not sure as i am new to this stuff.

Another question , why if Asp.netcore mvc is server side only and i must use js at client side , or it is server+ client part ? if so then why it is called server side technologiy ?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly to answer your 'design' question:
AngularJS and your REST APIs written in AspNet Core MVC is enough, you do not need any interface to consume your REST APIs.

To achieve this, AngularJs provides `$http services`, this [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) should help you get started.

For your another question about MVC.

MVC is a pattern, `Model-View-Controller` where each part has its own responsibility.
In AspNet MVC, View is usually rendered on the server side and all communication resides on the server, thus server side.

Let me know if you require more help on this.

Comment: Thanks alot , For the Design part , i am using ASP.Net Web APIs web services , NOT  AspNet core , is that a problem ? or still will work and doesn't need interface ?         For MVC , but  server view isn'T used by user right ? i mean why it is there given that client will only view the js - html views on client side -

Comment: REST APIs do not usually require an interface and can be consumed directly, in your case, your angularJS app will be both the interface and the client.

In MVC pattern, you can choose not to use the views, as you are using angularJS app, this will be your view for the application getting rendered on the client side and not on server side.

Also, you need to identify if you are using aspnetcore web API or aspnet framework.

I suggest you read up about REST APIs and MVC patterns, should help you give a better understanding of what you are doing :)